# Orion Leap Motion`Hand' does not exist in the type `Leap.Leap' - Compile error for core assets

Tags: unity, assets, scripting

I was playing with the example scenes provided by the [Core Assets pack](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/17770). Everything was working perfectly in Unity 5.3.2f1 until I opened the PinchingSandbox scene and added two script components to the HandControllerSandbox. I added Hand Cycler and Recording Controls. These scripts were available from the add component drop-down list. Naturally I planned to add my own code, but I first wanted to see if the scene would still run.

Instead of running I suddenly get hundreds of [AABB aabb errors](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-3-1f1-particle-system-errors-invalid-aabb-result-isfinite-d.374926/) which by the look of things is still an unresolved Unity issue. So, I remove the two script components but this doesn't resolve the issue. Perplexed, given that the PinchingSandbox scene worked fine just before I added those two scripts, I waste no time deleting the project and starting afresh.

I imported the unity core assets from the unity asset store like before and now I am very perplexed that I get the following error messages (I have tried reimporting the assets):

[image]

I am using [Orion](https://developer.leapmotion.com/get-started?id=v3-developer-beta&platform=windows&version=3.1.0.39495), and am not using VR just yet

### Related (here for reference)

- https://community.leapmotion.com/t/asset-cant-work-correctly-in-unity/1716 - except the assets worked before, so I shouldn't need Unity Pro
- https://community.leapmotion.com/t/error-from-new-leap-motion-core-assets-2-2-4/2759 - not exactly the error messages I get, but I have already tried reimporting so remain stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out to me by [Joe_Ward](https://community.leapmotion.com/t/compile-errors-with-the-unity-core-asset-examples/4794/2?u=frikster):

> Orion is not compatible with any earlier asset packages. You can use one or the other, but you cannot combine them.

And sure enough, I had tried importing both the [Leap Motion Core Assets](https://developer.leapmotion.com/unity) and the [Leap Motion Orion assets](https://developer.leapmotion.com/unity) which I had assumed were identical. Once I imported only one or the other the issue vanished. Consequentially, I can now add scripts and modify my virtual hand's behaviour with reckless abandon.